# How to set up two different codestyles inside PhpStorm project?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm starting on a big codebase which split between two architectures inside subfolders:

```
project/
├── old-architecture/    <-- PEAR Code style
└── new-architecture/    <-- PSR 1 and PSR 2 code style
```

I saw in [Configuring Code Style manual page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-code-style.html):

> The code styles are defined at the project level and at the IDE level (global).

I don't want to create two separate projects, because there are a lot of dependencies between old and new architectures. Also, development of the single feature will hit both architectures.

I knew about putting different editor configs in folders, but for example there is [no properties available for putting braces after `if` block](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties).

#### Maybe there are some lifehacks or solutions for such kind of configuration?

### Update, found:

- [community request "How to have multiple projects in same window?"](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206326369-How-to-have-multiple-projects-in-same-window-),
- [issue "Ability to open more then one related PhpStorm project in current frame"](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15187),
- [page "Opening Multiple Projects" in PhpStorm manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/opening-multiple-projects.html)

I will try to create two projects from subfolders. Each project will load the other one as a "Content root" folder. Will report results after some experiments.

Answer (score 0):

## Don't need to setup multiple projects.
You can safely use PSR-1&2
and it will be an acceptable PEAR code style

[I've checked differences](https://github.com/terales/pear-vs-psr-1-2/commit/b956b12170ffa8b353a8952085961f63e0ed7fda) between code style standards and found that there are only two differences between PEAR and PSR-1&2 on PhpStorm examples

#### `case` statement intendation

```
// PEAR                       |    // PSR-2
switch ($j) {                 |    switch ($j) {
case 0:                       |        case 0:
    $s1 = 'zero';             |            $s1 = 'zero';
    break;                    |            break;
default:                      |        default: 
    $s1 = 'other';            |            $s1 = 'other';
}                             |    }
```

Reference:

- [PEAR → Indenting and Line Length → Control Structures](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.control.php#standards.control)
- [PSR-2 → Control Structures → 5.2. switch, case](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#switch-case)

.

#### Several parameters per line

```
// PEAR                       |    // PSR-2
$colors = array(              |    $colors = array(
    "red", "green", "blue",   |        "red",
    "black", "white", "gray"  |        "green",
);                            |        "blue",
                              |        "black",
                              |        "white",
                              |        "gray"
                              |    );
```

Reference

- [PEAR: Several parameters per line are allowed](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.funcalls.php#standards.funcalls.splitfunccall)
- [PSR-2: there MUST be only one argument per line](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#method-and-function-calls)